# How to set Foreground Color in a ListBox single element?

Tags: c#, listbox, system.drawing

I'm doing a game. I have a list of users (nicks):

```
List<string> users;
```

This list is used to show to the users on a ListBox, call `listaJogadores`.

```
    public delegate void actualizaPlayersCallback(List<string> users);

    public void actualizaPlayers(List<string> users)
    {
        listaJogadores.BeginInvoke(new actualizaPlayersCallback(this.actualizarListaPlayers), new object[] { users });
    }

    public void actualizarListaPlayers(List<string> users)
    {
        listaJogadores.Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < users.Count; i++)
        {
            listaJogadores.Items.Add(users.ElementAt(i));
        }         
    }
```

When a user is playing, then it have is nick on the list of games:

```
List<Game> games;
```

What I want is when a player enter in a game, the color of is nick show in `listaJogadores`, must be Red!
When I have only one player in a game, everything is ok, all the players see the nick of that player in red, but when another player go to a game, then I get an *ArgumentOutOfRangeException* in the instruction `string nick = tmp.players.ElementAt(i).getNick();`

This is my code... Give me some ideas/help please! I think that the problem is the `for()`, but how can I manipulate an entire list without doing a loop?

```
listaJogadores.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;

private void listaJogadores_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.ControlText;
        Font drawFont = e.Font;

        for (int i = 0; i < games.Count; i++)
        {
            Game tmp;
            tmp = games.ElementAt(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < tmp.players.Count; j++)
            {
                string nick = tmp.players.ElementAt(i).getNick();

                if (listaJogadores.Items[e.Index].ToString() == nick)
                {
                    textBrush = Brushes.Red;//RED....
                    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) > 0)
                        drawFont = new Font(drawFont.FontFamily, drawFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
                }
                else if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) > 0)
                {
                    textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
                }
            }
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(listaJogadores.Items[e.Index].ToString(), drawFont, textBrush, e.Bounds);
    }
```

Comment: `string nick = tmp.players.ElementAt(i).getNick();`  the `i` here is the problem. you want to change that to `j` to solve the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put drawing logic inside of the loops, since you want to define the brush only once. First determine if the item is a player in a actual game. Then draw the item in the right color:

```
private void listaJogadores_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Index >= 0 && e.Index < listaJogadores.Items.Count) {
        e.DrawBackground();
        Brush textBrush = SystemBrushes.ControlText;
        Font drawFont = e.Font;
        bool playerFound = false;
        string nick = (string)listaJogadores.Items[e.Index];
        foreach (Game game in games) {
            if (game.players.Any(p => p.getNick() == nick)) {
                playerFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (playerFound) {
            textBrush = Brushes.Red;  //RED....  
            if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) > 0)
                drawFont = new Font(drawFont.FontFamily, drawFont.Size, FontStyle.Bold);
        } else if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) > 0) {
            textBrush = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
        }
        e.Graphics.DrawString(nick, drawFont, textBrush, e.Bounds);
        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
}
```

And also test if e.Index is valid. This might cause your "Index is out of bounds" Exception.

Comment: I would even add a method `bool IsPlaying(string nick)` to the game class. This would make the code more readable.

Comment: Mr. Olivier thanks for your help. I use your code and it's run fine for my purpose.

Comment: @user1038056 If Olivier's answer helped you the most, please feel free to click on the check mark next to his answer.  Also, learn to use the up and down vote buttons on the left.  Participation is good for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

check this code:

```
private void listaJogadores_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    listaJogadores.DrawItem-=Eeventhandle(listaJogadores_DrawItem);
    .
    .
    .
    listaJogadores.DrawItem+=Eeventhandle(listaJogadores_DrawItem);
}
```